# How can I prevent form submissions until previous onFormSubmit is finished.

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

I have written a form script that eliminates the chosen answer.  This means it has to process a function onFormSubmit.   While the script works, the end-user has to wait 30 seconds before they click resubmit or else the choice will not be eliminated.

Is there a way I can prevent submissions until the onFormSubmit function is completed?

Comment: yes it does work for preventing another submission. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this (thank you AdamL) using setAcceptingResponses(enabled).

```
function onFormSubmit(){
  var af = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var defaultClosedFor = af.getCustomClosedFormMessage();
  af.setCustomClosedFormMessage("The form is currently processing a submission, please refresh the page.");
  af.setAcceptingResponses(false);


<put your script stuff here>


   af.setAcceptingResponses(true);
  af.setCustomClosedFormMessage(defaultClosedFor);
}
```