# How to stop Google Form from accepting new response 30 seconds after the last Form Response?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to stop a Google Form from accepting a new response for 30 seconds after the last form response was submitted. After 30 seconds, the Form can accept new responses.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859895/how-can-i-prevent-form-submissions-until-previous-onformsubmit-is-finished/25938502#25938502) with a different message and adding a call to
Utilities.sleep(30000)